# How to get the values in a database table to an array using php code?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a beginner in the programming field..

My concept is just to move,to the home page from the login page after doing the checking of user id and password. i have a database table with fields 'user_id' & 'password'. so i want to get the datas from the table to array and then want to compare it with the values entered by the user...How is it possible in the most easiest way?

Comment: you can do that by using mysql_fech_array().

Comment: Learn how to use `if statements` then learn how to get data from MySQL, you've already learnt `redirects` then put it all together.

Comment: $sql="Select user_id,password from user_details";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
if (!$result)
  {
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
 $row = mysql_fetch_array ($result,MYSQL_BOTH );

My code is like this.. Then i want to take the content in 'row' to compare it with the text field entered.. How I get all the values to compare with using for loop...? Is it possible to check as row[0] row[1] etc....

Answer (score 0):

I always use

```
$query = "...";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $user_id = $row['user_id'];
    // ...
}
```

I think that should work better as you get an associative array, so you can work with the field names.
Note that if you're selecting `SUM(*)`, you have to put `$row['SUM(*)']` or give it a name via SQL.

Comment: or do `while(list($username, $password, $otherfield) = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {`, that's even more easy, because you can work with variables `$username`, `$password`, etc. in your loop

Answer (score 0):

Although you've shown little research and your question is quite broad, I'll show you an example that might give you some clues.

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); //escaping the string, will use it in a query
$password = $_POST['password'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) { // Expecting one result
     $userdata = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     if ($password == $userdata['password']) {
        // USER IS AUTHORISED
     } else {
        // USER IS NOT AUTHORISED
    }
}
```

This is a simple example.

Things to consider:

1. Although I did that in the example above to simplify things, do not store password as plaintext in the database - store a [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) hash instead. You can generate a hash by using `md5("string to hash")`. If you need help with that start another question.
2. After you have authorised the user you can "remember" that by using PHP sessions. Again, if you need help with that ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $username="username";  
    $password="password";  
    //Specify MySQL database to connect to  
    $database="database";  
    //Create connection and select the appropriate database  
    mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);  
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");  

    //Get the username and password from posted form  
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);  
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);  

    //Build the query to look for users that exist with that username/password combination  
    //Here I'm using the users table within my database  
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users where username=\"$username\" and password = \"$password\" ";  
    //Retrieve the results of the query, and also aquire the number of records returned  
    $result = mysql_query($query);  
    $num = mysql_numrows($result);  

    //Check to see how many records are returned  
    if ($num>0)  
    {  
        //User login was successful

        echo 'success login';
    } else {  
        //Login was unsuccessful
       echo 'user name not found';
    }
```

Comment: @arunrc: Do note use this code as it has a SQL Injection venerability

Comment: @MMM .. arunrc is beginner level...so its the easiest way for beginner.

Comment: @saba No, that's a lame excuse. You are not suppose to teach people how do to things wrongly. This is a very serious mistake and should not be made, ever. It is very easy to explain why he should be escaping his strings.

Comment: @arunrc: You need to escape your strings using `mysql_real_escape_string()` before you include them in your query (like `$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[username])`). This is performed in order to avoid someone editing your query by adding additional stuff at the end of the string.

Comment: as a beginner i really understood that code.. But  please explain the bug if there is any..

Comment: ok I have update my code... @arunrc you can use it...its save now.

Comment: @MMM: thanks for that... can u please explain what this mysql_real_escape_string() is for... i mean its function...

Comment: @arunrc - mysql_real_escape_string — Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement and prevent sql injections.

Comment: Before doing operations on POST data like this, you should check that the script was actually posted to, using `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

//HTML

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="password" name="password" />
<input type="submit" name="login"  value="login"/>
</form>
```

//PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
  $username=$_POST['username'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];

  $username=mysql_real_escape_string($username);
  $password=mysql_real_escape_string($password);
  $query = "select username,password from tableName
            where username='$username' and password='$password'";
$sql = mysql_query($query);

 if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1)
 {
   // Login success save username in session redirect to homepage
     header("location:homepage.php");
     exit();
 }
 else
 {
   // Display error message
 }
}
```

Comment: You have a few mistakes in your code. In your HTML, your value is missing a quotation mark. In your PHP, `$_POST['submit']` is not set, `mysql_real_escape_strings()` should be `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead, you need to put your variables in single quotation marks in your query like `username='$username'`. If you're only checking the number of rows you don't really need to select both username and password (to save memory).